# How to place multiple control in single pane

Tags: mfc

I am using Xtreme Toolkit Pro for creating docking pane in my MFC application.
The Pane class allows to attach only one control (which is inherited from CWnd class) at a time. I want to add multiple controls in my pane. How can I achive it?
If any one has an experience in this or relevant area please share it with me.

Info about Xtreme tool kit docking panes:
http://www.codejock.com/support/articles/mfc/dockingpane/dp_1.asp

Regards,
KK

Answer (score 2):

Through the builtin dialog editor you can create a window with multiple control

Make sure the properties Appearance>Style is set to "Child" and Behavior>SystemModal is set to "False".

Then just attach the Dialog window handle to the docking pane.